# How to drop columns using Rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord, rails-migrations

What's the syntax for dropping a database table column through a [Rails migration](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)?

Answer (score 1060, accepted):

```
remove_column :table_name, :column_name
```

For instance:

```
remove_column :users, :hobby
```

would remove the hobby Column from the users table.

Comment: @XåpplI'-I0llwlg'I-Thanks for the comment.  The change method can be used to drop a column in Rails 4 applications, but should not be used in Rails 3.  I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: You can also use `remove_column :table_name, :column_name, :type, :options` within the `change` method, since if you specify the type reverting the migration is possible.
From the documentation: _The `type`and `options` parameters will be ignored if present. It can be helpful to provide these in a migration's `change` method so it can be reverted. In that case, `type` and `options` will be used by add_column._

Comment: In Rails4, you can remove a column in the `change` method, but only if you specify the column type. E.g. `remove_column, :table_name, :column_name, :column_type`. Otherwise you'll get the following error when trying to run the migration: `remove_column is only reversible if given a type`

Comment: It might be worth noting in the main answer that [removing a column does not remove the corresponding index if it exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204476/will-removing-a-column-with-a-rails-migration-remove-indexes-associated-with-the)

Answer (score 411):

For older versions of Rails

```
ruby script/generate migration RemoveFieldNameFromTableName field_name:datatype
```

For Rails 3 and up

```
rails generate migration RemoveFieldNameFromTableName field_name:datatype
```

Comment: "rails g" can be used as an alternative to "rails generate"

Comment: `rails g migration remove_field_name_from_table_name field_name:datatype` also works

Comment: Note also that `AddXXXtoTTT` an `RemoveXXXFromTTT` may be followed by a white-spaced list of filed_name:data_type, and the appropriate add_column and remove_column statements will be created: `rails g migration RemoveUnusefulFieldsFromUsers hair_color:string favorite_number:integer` removes two attributes using a single migration. Note also that `remove_column` is not supported by `change` method, so you have to write both `up` and `down`.

Comment: Rails 4 seems to support `change` for this. Rollback works like it should.

Comment: I don't think you need the `field_name:datatype`. Removing is removing.

Comment: @AdamGrant I think that if you are using a `change` method that can be _reverted*_ you'll need to inform the data type (and all other field modifiers), so if you rollback that migration, the field can be correctly recreated. _* When I say reverted, that's in terms of database structure, of course, data from that column obviously will be lost._

Comment: @ClaudioFloreani your comment was really helpfull, many thanks

Answer (score 129):

Rails 4 has been updated, so the change method can be used in the migration to drop a column and the migration will successfully rollback.  Please read the following warning for Rails 3 applications:

**Rails 3 Warning**

Please note that when you use this command:

```
rails generate migration RemoveFieldNameFromTableName field_name:datatype
```

The generated migration will look something like this:

```
  def up
    remove_column :table_name, :field_name
  end

  def down
    add_column :table_name, :field_name, :datatype
  end
```

Make sure to not use the change method when removing columns from a database table (example of what you don't want in the migration file in Rails 3 apps):

```
  def change
    remove_column :table_name, :field_name
  end
```

The change method in Rails 3 is not smart when it comes to remove_column, so you will not be able to rollback this migration.

Comment: then run rake db:migrate

Comment: @Powers - brilliant and clear answer - would you be able to elaborate on the following: "The change method in Rails 3 is not smart when it comes to remove_column, so you will not be able to rollback this migration."

Comment: @BKSpurgeon - In Rails 3, if you use the `change` method, then the `rake db:rollback` command will error out.  `rake db:rollback` is basically the opposite of `rake db:migrate`.  This bug was fixed in Rails 4 :)

Comment: In Rails 4, I tried to rollback a change drop column. It fails and states you must specify data_type (as in your down code in your answer)

Comment: Same problem occured to me as to @rmcsharry. My rails version is 4.2.2 and i used change method. when i tried to rollback, error occured that remove_column is only reversible if given a type.

Answer (score 46):

In a rails4 app it is possible to use the change method also for removing columns. The third param is the data_type and in the optional forth you can give options. It is a bit hidden in the section 'Available transformations' on [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) .

```
class RemoveFieldFromTableName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :table_name, :field_name, :data_type, {}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 43):

There are two good ways to do this:

### remove_column

You can simply use remove_column, like so:

```
remove_column :users, :first_name
```

This is fine if you only need to make a single change to your schema.

### change_table block

You can also do this using a change_table block, like so:

```
change_table :users do |t|
  t.remove :first_name
end
```

I prefer this as I find it more legible, and you can make several changes at once.

Here's the full list of supported change_table methods:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_table

Answer (score 36):

### Clear & Simple Instructions for Rails 5 & 6

- **WARNING: You will lose data**.
- Warning: the below instructions are for trivial migrations. For complex migrations with e.g. millions of rows, read/write dbs, clusters, this advice is not for you:

---

## 1. Create a migration

**Run** the following command in your terminal:

`rails generate migration remove_fieldname_from_tablename fieldname:fieldtype` (Table name in plural, as per convention. [See the documentation here.](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) )

**Example:** `rails g migration RemoveAcceptedFromQuotes accepted:boolean`

### 2. Check the migration

```
# db/migrate/20190122035000_remove_accepted_from_quotes.rb
class RemoveAcceptedFromQuotes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  # with rails 5.2 you don't need to add a separate "up" and "down" method.
  def change
    remove_column :quotes, :accepted, :boolean
  end
end
```

### 3. Run the migration

`rake db:migrate` or `rails db:migrate` (they're both the same)

....And then you're off to the races!

Comment: now migrations can also be run as `rails db:migrate`

Answer (score 20):

Generate a migration to remove a column such that if it is migrated (`rake db:migrate`), it should **drop the column**. And it should **add column back** if this migration is rollbacked (`rake db:rollback`).

The syntax:

**remove_column :table_name, :column_name, :type**

> Removes column, also **adds column back** if migration is rollbacked.

Example:

```
remove_column :users, :last_name, :string
```

**Note**: *If you skip the data_type*, the migration will remove the column successfully but if you rollback the migration it will throw an error.

Answer (score 16):

in rails 5 you can use this command in the terminal:

```
rails generate migration remove_COLUMNNAME_from_TABLENAME COLUMNNAME:DATATYPE
```

for example to remove the column access_level(string) from table users:

```
rails generate migration remove_access_level_from_users access_level:string
```

and then run:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 14):

You can try the following:

```
remove_column :table_name, :column_name
```

([Official documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/remove_column))

Answer (score 14):

**Remove Columns For RAILS 5 App**

```
rails g migration Remove<Anything>From<TableName> [columnName:type]
```

Command above generate a migration file inside `db/migrate` directory. Snippet blow is one of remove column from table example generated by Rails generator,

```
class RemoveAgeFromUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    remove_column :users, :age
  end
  def down
    add_column :users, :age, :integer
  end
end
```

I also made a quick reference guide for Rails which can be found at [here](http://blog.li-xinyang.com/2016/09/06/d-0000/).

Answer (score 10):

```
rails g migration RemoveXColumnFromY column_name:data_type
```

X = column name 
Y = table name

**EDIT**

Changed `RemoveXColumnToY` to `RemoveXColumnFromY` as per comments - provides more clarity for what the migration is actually doing.

Comment: "Remove column **to** table" sounds strange, so **from** seems to be the better choice here.

Comment: @SebastianvomMeer yes I concur - the English reads much better with 'from'

Answer (score 9):

To remove the column from table you have to run following migration:

```
rails g migration remove_column_name_from_table_name column_name:data_type
```

Then run command:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 6):

`remove_column` in `change` method will help you to delete the column from the table.

```
class RemoveColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :table_name, :column_name, :data_type
  end
end
```

Go on this link for complete reference : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Answer (score 6):

For removing column from table in just easy 3 steps as follows:

1. write this command

`rails g migration remove_column_from_table_name`

after running this command in terminal one file created by this name and time stamp (remove_column from_table_name).

Then go to this file.

2. inside file you have to write

   `remove_column :table_name, :column_name`
3. Finally go to the console and then do

   `rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 5):

Give below command it will add in migration file on its own

```
rails g migration RemoveColumnFromModel
```

After running above command you can check migration file remove_column code must be added there on its own

Then migrate the db

```
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 5):

Heres one more from rails console

`ActiveRecord::Migration.remove_column(:table_name, :column_name)`

Answer (score 5):

Step 1: Create a migration

```
  rails g migration remove_column_name_from_table
```

Step 2: Change code in file migration just created

rails version < 3

```
  def change
    remove_column :table_name, :column_name, :datatype
  end
```

rails version >= 3

```
  def change
    remove_column :table_name, :column_name
  end
```

Step 3: Migrate

```
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Simple and clear

Answer (score 2):

Simply, You can remove column

```
remove_column :table_name, :column_name
```

For Example,

```
remove_column :posts, :comment
```

Answer (score 2):

first try to create a migration file running the command:

```
rails g migration RemoveAgeFromUsers age:string
```

and then on the root directory of the project run the migration running the command:

```
rails db:migrate
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Mark the column as ignored in the model

```rb
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  self.ignored_columns = ["my_field"]
end
```

2. Generate a migration

```sh
$ bin/rails g migration DropMyFieldFromMyModel
```

3. Edit the migration

```rb
class DropMyFieldFromMyModel < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    safety_assured { remove_column :my_table, :my_field }
  end
end
```

4. Run the migration

```sh
$ bin/rails db:migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

Through
`remove_column :table_name, :column_name`
in a migration file

You can remove a column directly in a rails console by typing:
`ActiveRecord::Base.remove_column :table_name, :column_name`

Answer (score 1):

Do like this;

`rails g migration RemoveColumnNameFromTables column_name:type`

I.e. `rails g migration RemoveTitleFromPosts title:string`

Anyway, Would be better to consider about downtime as well since the ActiveRecord caches database columns at runtime so if you drop a column, it might cause exceptions until your app reboots.

Ref: [Strong migration](https://github.com/ankane/strong_migrations#removing-a-column)

Answer (score 0):

you can use rails migration command

```
rails generate migration RemoveColumnNameFromTableName column_name:column_type
```

than you can migrate the database:

```
rails db:migrate
```

Answer (score -1):

Just run this in the rails console

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.remove_column("table_name", :column_name, :its_data_type)
```

or

```
TableName.find_by_sql(“ALTER TABLE table_name DROP column_name”)
```

Comment: I'm from the future and this is a terrible way to interact with your database.

Comment: why? is this not recommended? what if you want to do something from rails controller?