# How to remove a column from my Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to remove a few columns from my rails model which i already created and have some row entries in that model.
How to do it? Any links which has details for modifying the schema in rails ?
I'm using rails version 3.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

To remove a database column, you have to generate a migration:

```
script/rails g migration RemoveColumns
```

Then in the self.up class method, remove your columns:

```
def self.up
  remove_column :table_name, :column_name
end
```

You may want to add them back in the self.down class method as well:

```
def self.down
  add_column :table_name, :column_name, :type
end
```

The [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) for this goes into much more detail.

Comment: You don't have to specify `script/rails` with Rails 3. `rails g migration RemoveColumns` would suffice.

Answer (score 45):

If you know the columns you want to remove you can use the convention: Remove..From.. when naming your migrations. Additionally you can include the column names when running the migration command.

The form of the command:

```
rails g migration Remove..From.. col1:type col2:type col3:type
```

For example:

```
rails g migration RemoveProjectIDFromProjects project_id:string
```

generates the following migration file:

```
class RemoveProjectIdFromProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    remove_column :projects, :project_id
  end

  def self.down
    add_column :projects, :project_id, :string
  end
end
```

Comment: Did this change in Rails 4?  When I tried using your example it only generated a change method (no up/down methods).

Comment: @Dan - maybe. I haven't tried it in 4. 3 was the last time I tried this. I'll take a look later tonight and report back.

Comment: After a bit more research it looks like there is only supposed to be a change method in Rails 4.  The remove_column now takes a data type which must be how it handles adding the column back.

Comment: @Dan - I should mention that this Q is approp. tagged as ruby-on-rails-3 for this, so a new Q&A might be warranted w/ a link to this Q&A just to keep things connected.

Comment: This SO Q&A seems to have more on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831059/how-to-drop-columns-using-rails-migration. Power's answer mentions the diffs in 3 vs. 4 with this method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17792447/33204

Answer (score 10):

Via command alternative as `Add`, only change `Add` to `Remove`:

Single Column:

```
rails g migration RemoveColumnFromTable column:type
```

Multiple Columns:

```
rails g migration RemoveColumn1AndColumn2FromTable column1:type colummn2:type
```