# Rails: Can I spool off a column as a table in its own right?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, model

I'm using a model to track my dupermarket purchases.  The schema of the table representing items is:

```
CREATE TABLE "items"
 ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
  "barcode" varchar,
  "brand" varchar,
  "gendesc" varchar,
  "size" float,
  "unit_id" integer,
  "created_at" datetime NOT NULL,
  "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL);
```

Inclusion of `gendesc` (generic description, as a `varchar`) was a modeling mistake; I should have made this a foreign key, with the text descriptions in an additional table, as different brands of the same thing are equivalent for some but not all purposes of analysis.  So I want to replace the `gendesc` column with a `gendescs_id` column that is a foreign key for some `gedescs` table which would be equivalent to something created thus:

```
create table gendescs (id integer primary key, gendesc varchar);

select into gendescs(gendesc) distinct gendesc from items;
```

Is there a sequence of Rails migrations which does something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideal flow should be like this:

1. Create `gendescs` table. I will prefer not to name column as same as table name.

   **rails g model Gendesc value:string**
2. Add foreign key

   **rails g migration AddGendescToItem gendesc:references**
3. Run `rake db:migrate`
4. If you have data in `items.gendesc` column then you need to create entries for them in gendescs table. Run following code in rails console.

   ```
   Item.find_each do |i|
     g = Gendesc.find_or_create_by(value: i.gendesc)
     i.update(gendesc_id: g.id)
   end
   ```
5. Remove column gendesc from items table
   [How to remove a column from my Rails model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948804/how-to-remove-a-column-from-my-rails-model)
6. add belongs_to relationship to item model

   belongs_to: :gendesc