# Remove field from database without reset it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoose, database

I have this model Player:

```
"sport_id" : ObjectId("512db94e6ee1f54932000001"),
"team_id" : ObjectId("512dbaf36ee1f5523e00000a"),
"twitter" : false,
"twitter_account" : "@brianhartline",
"updated_at" : ISODate("2013-03-06T10:37:45.943Z"),
"version" : 7,
```

I have removed twitter from my model but database has field twitter. I dont want to drop the playerDB but I want to delete the twitter field in existing database.

what I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to remove the attribute like this

```
player.attributes.without('twitter')
```

Comment: i have to remove it on mongoDb

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Player.each do |player|
  player.unset(:twitter)
end
```

Comment: drinor i want twitter column should be removed in the database if i used ur code it will be  nil the database.

Comment: If you want remove twitter from database you should remove field from your Player model.

Comment: ya i done it before, but if exciting database has field twitter, i dont want to drop the playerDB i want to delete only the twitter field in exciting databse. what i have to do?

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831059/how-to-drop-columns-using-rails-migration

Comment: thanks, i drop the DB. link what u gave was is for ruby for me mongo is needed.

Comment: I don't check it but, see 'Remove a Field from a Document' in http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/update/#Updating-%24unset. For the next time xD.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in the mongo shell:

```js
db.players.update({}, {$unset: {twitter: 1}}, {multi: true})
```