# Rails 5: How to remove a column from a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the command for removing an existing column from a table using migration?

The column I want to remove is: `country:string`

From the table: `sample_apps`

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack overflow! I see your question already has answers, but I figured I should let you know, that one of the best places to get a good basic understanding of rails are the official Rails Guides:  http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org - they are surprisingly readable and will help you level up your basic Rails understanding super quick. The one specifically on migrations is this one: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html but I also recommend just reading them all from the beginning. :)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

To remove a column with migration:

```
rails g migration Remove..From.. col1:type col2:type col3:type
```

In your case:

```
rails g migration RemoveCountryFromSampleApps country:string
```

This will generate the following migration **in Rails 5.0**:

```
class RemoveCountryFromSampleApps < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    remove_column :sample_apps, :country, :string
  end
end
```

Comment: do I need to run `rails db:migrate` after this?

Comment: Just 1 more clarification. Since the model name SampleApp is singular and the table name sample_apps is plural, which one do I use? The `RemoveCountryFromSampleApp` or the `RemoveCountryFromSampleApps`

Comment: plural, just edited my answer ^^' for a full overview over migrations, you can check the brand new SO [Documentation section](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ruby-on-rails/1087/activerecord-migrations)

Comment: Is this reversible? What happens if I run `rails db:rollback`?

Answer (score 4):

Create migration file:

```
$ rails generate migration RemoveCountryFromSampleApps country:string
```

In generated migration file:

```
class RemoveCountryFromSampleApps < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
   remove_column :sample_apps, :country, :string
 end
end
```

Then run:

```
 rake db:migrate
```

Comment: In Rails 5 no more `rake` vs `rails` calls. Just use `rails`, always.

Answer (score 3):

To remove a column(country here) from table(sample_case)

```
rails generate migration RemoveCountryfromSampleCase country:string
```

Above command should generate a file *YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_remove_countryfrom_sample_case.rb*. under **db/migrate** folder

```
class RemoveCountryFromSampleCase < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    remove_column :sample_case, :country, :string
  end
end
```

In my case (I was doing it for more than two columns) only this appears

```
 class RemoveCountryFromSampleCase < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
  end
 end
```

**remove_column** line was not there so I added it manually and then fired the command

```
rails db:migrate
```

and it worked for me.

References https://stackoverflow.com/a/2963582
&
Ruby guide on Active Record migration
          https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Answer (score 1):

If want to remove the index too, you do with migration too:

```
rails g migration remove_post_id_from_comments post_id:integer:index
```

migration file:

```
class RemovePostIdFromComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_index :comments, :post_id
    remove_column :comments, :post_id, :integer
  end
end
```

then run: `rake db:migrate`

Comment: According the rails API documentation for `remove_column`: 
"Indexes on the column are automatically removed."
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-remove_column

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to specify the type?

Why not just `remove_column :sample_apps, :country` or `remove_column :comments, :post_id` for the samples here? Seems to work and removes a chance for error (text or string).

Comment: In my version not produce errors, it's just a pattern.
The type parameter not produce problems if differs from the original type.

Comment: You need to be specific about the types in case you will need to rollback